# Transpose data from records to columns without intermediate struct using serde Rust

Tags: json, struct, rust, deserialization

I have data structured in two different ways:

1: JSON

```
{
    "key1": 40,
    "key2": 50
{,
{
    "key1": 41,
    "key2": 51
}
```

2: nested array

```
[[40,50],[41,51]]
```

The goal is to deserialize this data (I receive both as `Strings`) into an Struct that looks like this:

```
struct data {
    key1: Vec<i8>,      // -> [40,41]
    key2: Vec<i8>       // -> [50,51]
}
```

I already have 2 methods for deserializing each type of data, but the problem is that for the first one, I have to create an intermediate `Struct` and collect them in a `Vec` to then iterate over this `Vec` pushing each element to its specific `Vec`s in the final `Struct`.
For the second one, I deserialize to a `Vec<Vec<i8>>` to then iterate again transposing into the final `Struct` element by element.

I read through all `serde` documentation and tried to find examples, but couldn't find a way of pushing directly to the final `Vec`s of the `Struct` without an intermediate step.
Does `serde` supports this? If so, how it's implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need a custom visitor for your array. Below is a working implementation.

Note that although we use additional enum `InnerData`, it does not require any additional allocations as this struct is only used in the stack. For every element of the outer array InnerData will be deserialized, and its fields pushed to the fields of the `Data` struct.

`#[serde(untagged)]` allows deserialization of the enum from flat variants (without specifying Map or Array in json).

Also not, that to use this type of deserialization, you need to specifically let the `Deserializer` know which `Visitor` to use. If your stuct is one of the feilds of another structure, you can specify this with `#[serde(deserialize_with = ...)]` attribute.

```
use serde::de;
use serde::de::Deserializer;
use serde::Deserialize;

const A: &str = "[{\"key1\": 40, \"key2\": 50}, {\"key1\": 41, \"key2\": 51}]";
const B: &str = "[[40, 50], [41, 51]]";

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    key1: Vec<i8>,
    key2: Vec<i8>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum InnerData {
    Map { key1: i8, key2: i8 },
    Array(i8, i8),
}

struct DataVisitor;

impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for DataVisitor {
    type Value = Data;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "invalid input")
    }

    fn visit_seq<A: de::SeqAccess<'de>>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error> {
        let mut result = Data {
            key1: vec![],
            key2: vec![],
        };
        while let Some(inner) = seq.next_element::<InnerData>()? {
            let (k1, k2) = match inner {
                InnerData::Map { key1, key2 } => (key1, key2),
                InnerData::Array(key1, key2) => (key1, key2),
            };

            result.key1.push(k1);
            result.key2.push(k2);
        }

        Ok(result)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut deserializer = serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(A);
    println!("{:?}", deserializer.deserialize_seq(DataVisitor {}));

    let mut deserializer = serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(B);
    println!("{:?}", deserializer.deserialize_seq(DataVisitor {}));
}
```

Fiddle: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f921adbb490970eb9a8b5ef5f9ab49d0

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what these deserializers would do, how to use them, or better yet provide code that shows what to do.

Comment: Maxim, could you add a code piece to demonstrate it?

Comment: @mbfernan I was actually wrong about the deserializer. After fiddling around a little, I came out with the working solution. I changed the answer, also adding some explanations to the code.